# Chrome extension not allowing external scripts from firebase

Tags: firebase, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I have added the following content security policy in my manifest

```
"content_security_policy":"script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com/ https://*.firebaseio.com https://www.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'",
```

and have the following code in the header of my HTML file:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.11.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

And yet I still get this issue when loading firebase/gstatic scripts in my popup html:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.11.0/firebase-app.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem:". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I have 3 other scripts that are also to be loaded in the header from gstatic, but they also fail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The warning you are getting says CSP is "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem:" Which is not what you're saying you have put in the manifest. So the CSP is coming from somewhere else. CSP can be set in headers on request for main html or as a meta tag, as well as in the manifest. So I'd start by checking there.